# bufferData vs bufferSubData - performance issues

Tags: webgl

I am experimenting with bufferData vs bufferSubData and noticed that the size of the underlying arraybuffer impacts performance when using bufferSubData.

```
_gl.bindBuffer(_gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.attributes.position.buffer)
if(init) _gl.bufferData(_gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.attributes.position.array, _gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)
else _gl.bufferSubData(_gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, new Float32Array(geometry.attributes.position.array.buffer,0,geometry.iPos))

_gl.enableVertexAttribArray( program.attributes.position )
_gl.vertexAttribPointer( program.attributes.position, 3, _gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0) 
_gl.drawArrays(_gl.TRIANGLES,0,geometry.iPos)
```

The bigger picture: I wrote a trail renderer and would like to preallocate a big array just to be sure not to run out of storage for the vertices created, geometry.iPos is the vertices counter - to avoid buffering the whole array I tried to use bufferSubData, with bufferData its even worse - but whats bugging me is that the size of the position array impacts performance when using bufferSubData, why is that and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I did tests and could not reproduce that behavior, even when buffering a 128mb sized array buffer the cost to update it via bufferSubData remained constant. Can you profile it?